# Solve a bit tricky system of equations

Tags: quadratics, systems-of-equations

I want to solve the system for $x$, $y$ and $z$. Is there any smart trick to solve it?

$$\begin{cases} 2a(ax+by)+2c(cx+dy)+2zx=0 \\ 2b(ax+by)+2d(cx+dy)+2zy=0 \\ x^2+y^2-1=0\end{cases}$$

$a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ and $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$. It is a part of another problem I am working on.

Comment: What does "not any $z$ in the answer" mean?  Are you assuming $z$ is 0, or something else?

Comment: It is a variable. What I meant was that I am only interested of the solutions for x and y. But no harm if I get the solution for x,y and z.

Comment: But what a "solution for $x$ and $y$" even mean? If you don't know what $z$ is, how can you show that the first equation is true?  (Or do you mean $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$?)

Comment: Okey, I did some edits. It is a part of a problem using the Lagrange method and I am quite sure that it has a solution.

Comment: Please post the original problem or, at least, the Lagrange multipliers formulation.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to optimize some function where your two variables are restricted to lie on a circle with radius 1 (assuming $z$ is the Lagrange multiplier associated with the constraint). Maybe you're better served if you were to make some transformation to polar coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitutions

$$
a=R_1 \cos(\phi_1), b=R_1\sin(\phi_1) \\
c=R_2 \cos(\phi_2), d=R_2\sin(\phi_2) \\
x=\cos (\theta), y=\sin(\theta)
$$
Eliminate $z$ to get an equation in $\theta$
$$\sin \left(3\,\left(\theta-{  \phi_2}\right)\right)\,
 {  R_2}^3+\sin \left(\theta-{  \phi_2}\right)\,{  R_2}^3+
 \sin \left(3\,\left(\theta-{  \phi_1}\right)\right)\,{  R_1}^3
 +\sin \left(\theta-{  \phi_1}\right)\,{  R_1}^3=0$$